# Join query result in duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
-----------tblDListTest---------
id      listid      trackingcode
1       125         trc1
2       125         trc1
3       125         trc1
4       126         trc4
5       126         trc5

---------------------------------


---------tblTrcWeightTest----------
id      weight      trackingcode
1       20          trc1
2       30          trc1
3       40          trc1
4       50          trc4
5       70          trc5
```

Need to display trackingcode and with their weight.
In tblDListTest, there are 3 records against listid 125.
I want to display only 3 records with weight.

I am using query :

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select DL.id, DL.listid, DL.trackingcode, tw.weight
from tblDListTest DL
inner join tblTrcWeightTest tw on DL.trackingcode = tw.trackingcode
where DL.listid = 125
```

My query result :

```
id  listid      trackingcode    weight
1   125         trc1            20
1   125         trc1            30
1   125         trc1            40
2   125         trc1            20
2   125         trc1            30
2   125         trc1            40
3   125         trc1            20
3   125         trc1            30
3   125         trc1            40
```

But I want following result .

```
id  listid      trackingcode    weight
1   125         trc1            20
2   125         trc1            30
3   125         trc1            40
```

Comment: `where tblDListTest.id = 1` would do it, but why the duplicates in the table? What do they mean?

Comment: You join on `trackingcode`, so naturally you combine all `tblDListTest` with all `tblTrcWeightTest` with the same trackingcode. But it seems you want to pick certain combinations (e.g. `tblDListTest.ID = 1` with `tblTrcWeightTest.ID = 1`) and dismiss others (e.g. `tblDListTest.ID = 1` with `tblTrcWeightTest.ID = 2`). By what rule do you want to pick the pairs?

Answer (score 0):

you need a unique key (any combination of fields that results on a unique value) in one of the tables.
In your example, `trc1` appears 3 times in each table.
SQL doen't know to join this data, so, it will make a cartesian product of the possible combinations.

If you can't use a unique value in the join, you can use a `SELECT DISTINCT DL.id, DL.listid, DL.trackingcode, tw.weight ....`

Comment: @Rizwan Ali: If you add `distinct` to your query, you get the same nine rows as before, because no two rows are exactly the same (there are no two rows with the same `id` *and* the same `weight`). Besides, using `distinct` to get rid of duplicates is almost always a sign of an inappropriate or even flawed query. In your case you should be able to name the rules on how to join, which you haven't been able to do so far. Maybe it is even the database that is flawed and the difficulties to write the query are just the consequence of that.

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicates between your tables. You would want to see something like this:

```
;WITH DL (id, listid, trackingcode) AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(int, id), listid, trackingcode FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1','125','trc1'), 
            ('2','125','trc1'), 
            ('3','125','trc1'), 
            ('4','126','trc4'), 
            ('5','126','trc5')
    ) AS A (id, listid, trackingcode)
),
tw (id, weight, trackingcode) AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(int, id), weight, trackingcode FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1','20','trc1'), 
            ('2','30','trc1'), 
            ('3','40','trc1'), 
            ('4','50','trc4'), 
            ('5','70','trc5')
    ) AS A (id, weight, trackingcode)
)

SELECT DISTINCT DL.listid,
    DL.trackingcode,
    tw.weight
FROM DL
INNER JOIN tw ON DL.trackingcode = tw.trackingcode
WHERE DL.listid = 125
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values and then use that for the `join`:

```
select dl.id, dl.listid, dl.trackingcode, tw.weight
from (select dl.*, row_number() over (partition by trackingcode order by id) as seqnum
      from tblDListTest dl
     ) dl inner join
     (select tw.*, row_number() over (partition by trackingcode order by id) as seqnum
      from tblTrcWeightTest tw
     ) tw
     on dl.trackingcode = tw.trackingcode and dl.seqnum = tw.seqnum
where dl.listid = 125;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use something like this.

```
DECLARE @tblDListTest table (
    ID INT,
    listid INT,
    trackingcode VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @tblTrcWeightTest table (
    ID INT,
    weight INT,
    trackingcode VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @tblDListTest (ID,listid,trackingcode)
VALUES (1, 125, 'trc1'),
       (2, 125, 'trc1'),
       (3, 125, 'trc1'),
       (4, 126, 'trc4'),
       (5, 126, 'trc5')

INSERT INTO @tblTrcWeightTest (ID,weight,trackingcode)
VALUES (1, 20, 'trc1'),
       (2, 30, 'trc1'),
       (3, 40, 'trc1'),
       (4, 50, 'trc4'),
       (5, 70, 'trc5')


SELECT A.ID, A.listid, A.trackingcode, B.weight 
FROM @tblDListTest A
JOIN @tblTrcWeightTest B ON B.ID = A.ID
WHERE  A.listid = 125
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select twt.id, tt.listid, twt.trackingcode, twt.weight
from tblTrcWeightTest twt cross apply (
     select top 1 tdt.listid
     from tblDListTest tdt
     where tdt.trackingcode = twt.trackingcode
) tt
where twt.trackingcode = 'trc1';
```